# C# DateTime Submit method

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone help me to figure out as to why I am getting this error message, when I didn't enter in any date or time when I click the submit button?

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   Nullable object must have a value.

[image: Error]

```
 int result1 = this.startDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.Date);
        int result2 = this.endDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.CompareTo(this.startDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date);

        if (result1 >= 0 && result2 > 0)
        {
            //To Do navigate to sprint dashboard
            // var userProjects = new UserStory();
            //var sprintDashboardPage = new SprintDashboardPage(usersProjects);
            //var mainWindow = this.GetWindow() as MainWindow;
            //mainWindow.MainFrame.Navigate(sprintDashboardPage);
            this.ErrorMessage = "Date is VALID";
            this.CloseWindow();
        }
        else
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "Choose Valid Date";
        }
```

Comment: it's hard to tell without more details, so maybe it'd be worth debugging the application in order to identify the null instance. I'm guessing you're using a [`DatePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx), and if that's the case then its `SelectedDate` property is `null` and you should check it before using it, as @AramKocharyan noted.

Answer (score 2):

`this.startDate.SelectedDate` is a `Nullable<DateTime>`. This means you have to check whether `this.startDate.SelectedDate` has a value assigned before using it by doing:

```
if(this.startDate.SelectedDate.HasValue) {
    this.startDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.Date);
}
```

The following will also work:

```
if(this.startDate.SelectedDate != null) {
    this.startDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.Date);
}
```

Same applies when accessing `this.endDate.SelectedDate`.

In C#, `DateTime` is Value Type which means it must always have a value assigned to it. In other words, it can't be set to null. Its default value is `DateTime.MinValue`. `Int32` (or `int`) is another example of a Value Type and it's default value is 0.

In order to make a Value Type support null, you can wrap it with `Nullable<>`. Doing so means that you have to explicitly check whether a value has been assigned before accessing the value, or an InvalidOperationException will be thrown.

The DateTime picker control in WPF returns a `Nullable<DateTime>` object so that you can know whether a user has actually selected a value in the control, as it will be set a non-null value.

Comment: Being built-in has nothing to do with whether something is a ValueType or not. Suggesting it is could cause more confusion than you dispell.

Comment: @JonHanna, thanks. I knew there was a name for it that was at the tip of my tongue, but it was eluding me even when I tried to Google search it. I was therefore hoping someone would come and correct me. I have updated to include the correct description.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `Value` property on a `Nullable<>` without first checking its `HasValue` property returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown in the `.Value` property of the `DateTime?` (nullable DateTime), as it is required to return a `DateTime`, but it can't  because there's no `DateTime` to return.

It is a bad idea to access `.Value` property of Nullable type without checking it. You should consider adding null-checking code. ( e.g. with `HasValue` property )

Comment: How do you go about in doing that? `Nullable<DateTime> MyNullableDate;
            int result1 = this.startDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.CompareTo(MyNullableDate.Now.Date);'` -- I have tried that but I am getting error message under `NOW` @Aram

Comment: @xasmer, `this.startDate.SelectedDate` is already a `Nullable<DateTime>`. You need to call `this.startDate.SelectedDate.HasValue` before using it! In your above comment, you have just introduced a second `Nullable<DateTime>` but you still didn't check for null before using it!